# getting exception while geeting json data along with http files

Tags: json, asp.net-core-webapi

[image: Api Exception]

i am sending the data through postman to asp.net webapi. But i am getting the exception.Need to send both file and json data.

[image: Data passing through post man.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the json format also in C# coding as string.

```
public JsonResult FileUploadDetails(HttpPostedFileBase[] Files,string request)
       {

           //Stream req = Request.InputStream;
           //string reqparm = Request.QueryString["request"];
           //req.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
           //var jsonStr = new StreamReader(reqparm).ReadToEnd();
           JObject obj = JObject.Parse(request);
            .................
              ...............
       }
```